# Don't know how and where to deploy my truffle project

Tags: node.js, blockchain, truffle, decentralized-applications

**Deployed smart conract on polygon(test net) using truffle, Don't know how and where to deploy my truffle project(i.e containing html frontend and node.js backend).**
I am a beginner at blockchain, I have created a registration form and storing on blockchain then reading those details back, it is working perfectly on localhost + polygon(testnet). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your dapp up on netlify ( https://www.netlify.com/ )  for free and then deploy the contract to the Polygon mainnet. It will be cheaper than most other chains. You will need to get some MATIC to cover the gas fees.